# &nbsp; vs &Alpha; displaying in browser and source

Tags: html, sql, ascii, coldfusion-10

I would like `&Alpha;` to display as A in the browser, but remain `&Alpha;` in my source code.  My reason is that I would like to store the code in a SQL table as `&Alpha;`.  However, anytime I add the literal `&Alpha;` and view the source code, I see A.  Since this text might be resent back to the database (as input in a form), I lose the `&Alpha;` version.

I don't seem to have this problem with the `&nbsp;` which is the behavior I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *this text might be resent back to the database*  From what you have described, it sounds like the problem is not the source code. As mentioned below, the value `&Alpha;` *will* remain in the source code.  However, when the form is submitted, the browser submits the *rendered value* - `A` (not what is in the source code ie `&Alpha;`). So `A` is what gets saved to your database table.  The next time you retrieve that column from the database it will no longer contain `&Alpha;`, which would explain why you are seeing `A` in the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&Alpha;` stays the same when viewing the source code in a separate browser window. I inserted `&Alpha;` into my own MySQL table called 'test' using the command below, and it remains the same.

```
INSERT INTO test (column1, column2) VALUES ('&Alpha;', '&nbsp;');
```

Perhaps you were using an element inspector to view the source code? That is when `&Alpha;` will appear as A. This happens to other special character codes such as `&copy;` (©) and `&#9658;` (►).

If this is the case, then consider right clicking and selecting View Page Source or similar option instead.

Comment: Yes, &Alpha; does stay the same in the source. However, it sounds like he is using it in a text field, which is then submitted to an action page. Typically, that will submit the value `A`, which would then be saved in the database, rather than the original text `&Alpha;`.

Comment: The issue was not "viewing source" and viewing through an element inspector.  Thanks Much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode and decode your Html while storing to the database. Here is a Few links to help you.

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464984.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

It's crucial to set the right character encoding in your (html) views, database, tables, etc. I recommend UTF-8. Then, it's not specially need to to encode.

Secondly, no "forced" encoding means also you can simply (re)use the text in non web/html views